# SQL query FOR XML Path Root 

Tags: sql-server

I want to display column called SampleDate from table SampleTable where column SampleAgencyName = something and below the date I want to display the value of a column called SampleNumber.

I mean the results should be something like this.

```
 <tr>
    <td> 
    Date1
    SampleNumber1
    </td>
    <td> 
    Date2
    SampleNumber2
    </td>
    </tr>
```

I want to do this using FOR XML Path Root in SQL SERVER.

I can get just the dates to work easily.

```
SELECT SampleDate 'td' from SampleTable T where SampleAgencyName = 'something' for xml path('tr'), root('table')
```

My issue how to get the value for the SampleNumber column under the date.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @RedFilter ...I have posted what I have tried!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT SampleDate + '    ' + SampleNumber 'td' from SampleTable T where SampleAgencyName = 'something' for xml path('tr'), root('table')
```

Cast the colums as varchar in case any of them is numeric

In place of space you can use char(13) this will give the results in next line

```
SELECT SampleDate + char(13)
 + SampleNumber 'td' from SampleTable T where SampleAgencyName = 'something' for xml path('tr'), root('table')
```